# Is PHP's extended CHM manual gone?

Tags: php, reference, manual

Where can I find an updated version of the extended PHP manual (with user comments) for download?

The [usual URL](http://www.php.net/docs-echm.php) redirects to [the general docs download page](http://www.php.net/download-docs.php), was this version discontinued?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now (since 25-Jun-2011) it seems to be back (for good?)

- http://www.php.net/download-docs.php

Answer (score 4):

It is no longer produced:

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48707&edit=1

Comment: Is because there is no Windows box to produce it or there are some other reasons?

Comment: The bug page above says quite clearly that we don't have people with time or resources for it.

Answer (score 0):

And now it has been revisited. Just check back on your link..

Comment: It was named php-manual-extended.chm but when I download it, It is the normal one.... fool PHP